# docker COPY without save point

Tags: docker

I would like to COPY a really big file from the host filesystem to the guest

http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#copy

but I want to use the file immediately in a shell script and throw it away, so that the save point is AFTER the script.

However, it would appear that `COPY` creates a save point and anybody using my resulting image will have to download this large file. In my case, this results in about 5GB of needless data.

Is there a way to copy a file from the local filesystem without invoking a save point?

Comment: I just started using Docker a couple months ago.  Although, I don't know the actual answer to your question, I thought I'd suggest a possible work-around.  You could try hosting the file locally (or as close as possible) and then just do a `wget` in your script.  That way, you can use the file and throw it away as desired without creating the save point (until after the script has completed - depending on how your running the script).  But, honestly, I don't know if that would still increase the size of the overall image.

Comment: hehe, yeah, if we're going the "hack" route I'd thought of that one too. It would work if the file was deleted within the same `RUN` as `curl`s it. Let's call it plan B.

Comment: One man's "hack" is another man's "work-around".  LOL.  Seriously though, I'm also interested in knowing the Docker way of doing this.  I wonder what would happen if you added the file to `.dockerignore` before running `docker build`.

Comment: Docker volumes is the way to include a file without it becoming part of the image file system. Is it feasible to run container as follows? "docker -v /local/path/to/big/file:/docker/path/to/big/file .."

Comment: @dcarrith heh, I suppose the file should really be ignored as soon as it is added, and therefore not available. dockerignore doesn't work in docker hub, but this is for a local image so would be feasible if it worked.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor that is actually a reasonable workaround. `VOLUME` is allowed in build scripts. Not sure about umounting though.

Comment: Using a VOLUME instruction won't work; you can't mount a host folder inside a Dockerfile. The only solution I know of is the previously suggested wget one.

Comment: Why not use `ENTRYPOINT` for this purpose? When container starts first time, you can load your file, use it and then delete it.

Comment: @VitalyIsaev that'll only work on my machine, which would be kinda useless to be honest.